# Are there classes available somewhere for HTML elements in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I would like to write some TypeScript functions that operate only on Checkbox elements. It would be most fun to declare the functions to have only Checkbox arguments. Otherwise, I have two choices, (a) the calling code selects what it thinks is a Checkbox and passes that, or it passes an ID, and I must select the Checkox and decide what to do if the rules are broken and two or more elements have that ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HTMLInputElement` interface in lib.d.ts defines the general `<input>` tag (as described by the DOM definition); Checkboxes will have `type` as "checkbox"

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if or how I could derive from HTMLInputElement?